# 'Manager' classes as List of objects

Tags: c#, oop

I'm actually in the design phase for refactoring project (we're making a software all again, because it was based on a God Class).

So, I've learned a lot about design and we've used the Unified Process to reach a decoupled class diagram as result. Now, we're writing some piece of code (just like a draft or something) to validate the Model we have been developing, and I'm struggling in the creation of some classes:

First, I try always to follow the **Single Responsibility Principle**, and that leads me to the problem:

I have two classes: `Camera` (the camera connected to the PC) and `HeadSensor` (the group of many physical devices connected to the PC, which will be used together with the camera).

The point is, my software starts checking all the Cameras and instantiating the connected ones. I've created a `CameraManager` class that groups all of them, as you can see below:

```
class CameraManager
{
    private List<ICamera> _cameras = new List<ICamera>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<ICamera> Cameras => new List<ICamera>(_cameras).AsReadOnly();

    public ICamera this[string serial] => _cameras.Find(camera => camera.Serial == serial);

    public void LoadCameras()
    {
        // Still not implemented code, as we're in the design phase.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And, after the user selects which Head Sensors are connected to each Camera (that I won't specify now), the software should create a `HeadSensor` via another manager, the `HeadSensorManager`:

```
public class HeadSensorManager
{
    private List<HeadSensor> _headSensors = new List<HeadSensor>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<HeadSensor> HeadSensor => new List<HeadSensor>(_headSensors).AsReadOnly();

    public HeadSensor this[int index] => _headSensors.ElementAt(index);

    public void CreateHeadSensor(ICamera camera)
    {
        if (this[camera.Serial] != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The selected Camera is already connected to a Head Sensor.");
        }
        _headSensors.Add(new HeadSensor(camera));
    }
}
```

As you can see, this class checks if there is no existing HeadSensor that uses the passed Camera.

Finally, my question is: is there a design pattern to implement this the best way? Because I read here that `Manager` is not a good name to classes, and maybe it has many more responsabilities than "grouping" my HeadSensors.

Looking for an answer, the *Factory* design pattern doesn't fit too well on what I want to do, should I create a new class or is this okay?

Don't know if I'm being clear in this, but I could not find any on this topic.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right site to post this question. If the code works and you need a review of your code then you should post at CodeReview

Comment: [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) might also be a better exchange than [so].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about design rather than a specific coding problem. A better forum would be https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yeah - look up `Inversion of Control`, aka IoC. You're doing too much there with the manager classes. If you ever have to refactor things, these manager classes are going to be like that bad rug that got glued down to the hardwood floor. A more atomic level of coding might result in those classes using dependency-injection of a smaller version of the manager class to help track camera usage. Basically, you're inverting the whole arrangement. It takes time to get your head around it...

Comment: @Igor when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @DeanOC see above ^^^

Comment: Thank you everyone for the hel provided here. Just need bit more understanding of the stack overflow rules :) - so, can I move this question to Code Review?